# Python - object has no attribute

Tags: python

I'm getting this error:
"*Run - exceptions.AttributeError:'Switchbot' object has no attribute 'Option2Value'*" -

When I'm running this code:

```
    def LoadEditLines(self):
    self.Option1SlotBar = ui.SlotBar()
    self.Option1SlotBar.SetParent(self)
    self.Option1SlotBar.SetSize(29, 14)
    self.Option1SlotBar.SetPosition(40, 44)
    self.Option1SlotBar.SetWindowHorizontalAlignCenter()
    self.Option1SlotBar.Show()

    self.Option1Value = ui.EditLine()
    self.Option1Value.SetParent(self.Option1SlotBar)
    self.Option1Value.SetSize(29, 18)
    self.Option1Value.SetPosition(6, 0)
    self.Option1Value.SetMax(4)
    self.Option1Value.SetNumberMode()
    self.Option1Value.SetText("0")
    self.Option1Value.SetFocus()
    self.Option1Value.SetTabEvent(ui.__mem_func__(self.Option2Value.SetFocus))
    self.Option1Value.SetReturnEvent(ui.__mem_func__(self.Option2Value.SetFocus))
    self.Option1Value.Show()

    self.Option2SlotBar = ui.SlotBar()
    self.Option2SlotBar.SetParent(self)
    self.Option2SlotBar.SetSize(29, 14)
    self.Option2SlotBar.SetPosition(40, 79)
    self.Option2SlotBar.SetWindowHorizontalAlignCenter()
    self.Option2SlotBar.Show()

    self.Option2Value = ui.EditLine()
    self.Option2Value.SetParent(self.Option2SlotBar)
    self.Option2Value.SetSize(29, 18)
    self.Option2Value.SetPosition(6, 0)
    self.Option2Value.SetMax(4)
    self.Option2Value.SetNumberMode()
    self.Option2Value.SetText("0")
    self.Option2Value.SetTabEvent(ui.__mem_func__(self.Option3Value.SetFocus))
    self.Option2Value.SetReturnEvent(ui.__mem_func__(self.Option3Value.SetFocus))
    self.Option2Value.Show()
```

PS: I'm a newbie in Python (and codding).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about debugging code hosted off-site that's over a thousand lines long.

Comment: I hope now is on-topic... :-?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On line 380 you're referencing Option2Value before you actually create it on line 393. Ensure all the items are created THEN attach the event listeners that reference other items.

Comment: Yes, that worked, but now i have a new problem if you want to check out. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @AndreiStanila99 You should make a new question (not edit your current one). Now my answer makes no sense because it's in reference to something that no longer exists. Stackoverflow is also so other people can benefit from the answers. That was probably a long short for this question anyway, but you really should edit it back and make a new question.

Comment: I'm sorry, I will edit back so your answer makes sense and create a new question.